# Bootstrap strange grid alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

May some of you explain me why my bootstrap grid is acting strange ?

The final result must be like the picture below :
[image]

But when i code it and check it browser version vs psd version mine is different... what is going on ? The boxes in red are from my browser view ( chrome ).

[image]

Any clue ?

```css
.facts { color: #fff; background: linear-gradient(  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)), url(https://s27.postimg.org/7kjcvsxc3/facts_bg.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat; background-size: cover; padding: 40px 0; width: 100%; min-height: 505px; }
.facts-content { text-align: center; }
.facts-content h3 { font-family: "Gotham-Book", sans-serif; font-size: 47px; line-height: 55px; padding: 0 5px; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 38px 0 41px 0; }
.facts-content h3 span { color: #00c0ff; }

.item h4 { font-family: "Gotham-Black", sans-serif; font-size: 40px; line-height: 49px; padding: 0 5px;  }
.item h4 > span { font-family: "Gotham-Light", sans-serif; }
.item p { font-family: "Lato-Regular", sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px; padding: 0 5px;  }
.item a { display: block; margin-bottom: 27px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="facts">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="facts-content">
      <h3>some <span>facts</span> about us</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/z29j3y5s1/ideas.png" width="124" height="124" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
            <h4>14<span>&#37;</span></h4>
            <p>Proin hendrerit velit a lectus vel nibh tincidunt</p>
          </div>
          <!-- item -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-3 -->

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/4jjqizgld/green_earth.png" width="125" height="126" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
            <h4>25<span>&#37;</span></h4>
            <p>Proin hendrerit velit a lectus vel nibh tincidunt</p>
          </div>
          <!-- item -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-3 -->

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/4yzlpqrwh/leafs.png" width="126" height="126" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
            <h4>75<span>&#37;</span></h4>
            <p>Proin hendrerit velit a lectus vel nibh tincidunt</p>
          </div>
          <!-- item -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-3 -->

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/5d0xpcc01/solar_panels.png" width="130" height="132" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
            <h4>90<span>&#37;</span></h4>
            <p>Proin hendrerit velit a lectus vel nibh tincidunt</p>
          </div>
          <!-- item -->
        </div>
        <!-- col-md-3 -->
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- facts-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- facts -->
```

Comment: Everything looks fine in the full page code snippet. Check to make sure all of you elements have proper closing tags, and are there other CSS rules you have applied to the whole project that are not included in this question?

Comment: yes i have more code but it is not related with this section of the page, I already checked about that and yes I also checked for open tags and I do not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're concerned about specific pixel alignment, don't be. In a mobile world with so many different screen sizes and resolutions, counting in exact pixels doesn't make a lot of sense. Your output looks good and captures the spirit of the PSD. Don't try to line things up 100% exactly. It's a futile effort that adds virtually no benefit.